# navigationBottomBar

Tags: android, android-xml, coordinator-layout

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/linear_layout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.akmaral.application.MainActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/appbarlayout"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:id="@+id/container"            
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             />
    <com.aurelhubert.ahbottomnavigation.AHBottomNavigation
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Как сделать `bottomNavigationBar` фиксированным(не исчезающим при прокрутке `recyclerview`)?

`recyclerview` находится во фрагменте. И чтобы `bottomNavigationBar` находился под `framelayout` и не перекрывал последний элемент `recyclerview`.

Comment: bottomNavigationBar в разметке этого же фрагмента лежит?

Comment: bottomNavigationBar находится в MainActivity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Положите главную разметку в корневой `RelativeLayout` и у container-a выставьте атрибут `android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_navigation"`

Comment: спасибо)) работает